# How to get System IP from a Dot net Core application running inside a Docker container

Tags: docker, .net-core, amazon-ec2

I have deployed a .NET Core 3.1 application using Docker in AWS Cloud. I tried to get the system IP(Not Docker container IP) many ways, but all the time I'm getting Docker Container IP.

Is there any way to get the System IP where the Docker container is running?

```
Environment.MachineName();


private string LocalIPAddress()
    {
        IPHostEntry host;
        string localIP = "";
        host = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
        foreach (IPAddress ip in host.AddressList)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ip.ToString());
            if (ip.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
                localIP = ip.ToString();
        }
        //return localIP;
        return host.HostName + ", " + Environment.MachineName;
    }
```

Comment: Sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Finding the "system" IP address is less useful than you might think at first. What exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 4):

There is no way for an application in a container to automatically determine "the system ip".

While there are some processes that *might* work (such as making a request to an external service like https://icanhazip.com to find your "externally visible" address), these will often produce an answer that is not useful:

- Maybe your system has multiple ips, and the process returns the wrong one.
- Maybe your externally visible ip address comes from a proxy or NAT gateway, and has nothing to do with addresses actually available on your host.
- Etc.

The only reliable way for a containerized service to know something about the host is either (a) to run the application in the host network namespace (`docker run --net=host`) or (b) to pass in the information as an environment variable (`docker run -e MY_SYSTEM_IP=1.2.3.4 ...`) or some sort of configuration file, etc.

(If your goal is simply to connect to a service running on the host -- and I didn't think that was what you were asking -- you do have a few options, which differ depending on whether you're running under Linux, or MacOS/Windows.)

Comment: Thanks. I just need the server IP for logging. Will check the options you provided.